# How to extract ZIP file internally and add the new name to an Observable Collection?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp, zip

Working on a UWP app. a part of the app is to create themes from pictures packaged in a Zip file.
so here is the file picker and the unpacking process.

```
private async void FilePickerWallpaperDynamic(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        FileOpenPicker pickerWallpaperDynamic = new FileOpenPicker
        {
            ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail,
            SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary
        };
        pickerWallpaperDynamic.FileTypeFilter.Add(".zip");

        StorageFolder localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        StorageFolder createdynamicFolder = await localFolder.CreateFolderAsync("Dynamic", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        StorageFolder dynamicFolder = await localFolder.GetFolderAsync("Dynamic");
        StorageFile fileName = await pickerWallpaperDynamic.PickSingleFileAsync();
        if (fileName != null)
        {
            selectedDynamicThemeName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName.Name);
            StorageFolder addedTheme = await dynamicFolder.CreateFolderAsync(selectedDynamicThemeName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            await ExtractToDirectoryAsync(fileName.Path, addedTheme.Path);
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
    }
}


public static async Task ExtractToDirectoryAsync(string zipFilePath, string destinationDir)
{
    await Task.Run(() => ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipFilePath, destinationDir));
}
```

The app is successfully setting the correct paths and names. however, when selecting a zip file from local libraries on the internal storage i am met with a message saying access is denied. when trying from a removable storage the app crashes.

Comment: Please check the debug output for messages. Read everything in the debug output.

Comment: I have checked it and nothing seems out of the ordinary. This error appears when selecting a zip file:
_The thread 0x1410 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x23d4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[9412] Wallpaper.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff)._

Comment: The code in the question has no exception handling at all. Add that and see if the exception gets caught

Comment: I have added all exceptions, non of which got caught !

Comment: Both FilePickerWallpaperDynamic and LoadThemes have no exception handling.

Comment: I have used this [Method](https://stackify.com/csharp-exception-handling-best-practices/) to add exception handling to the code. the results remain the same

Comment: That not a single method that's a full page of theory about exception handling. Add try/catch to these methods.

Comment: I finally figured it out … I was working on it all day. the problem is the fallowing!

it is the Unzip operation:


_Synchronous operations should not be performed on the UI thread.  Consider wrapping this method in Task.Run._

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd I have changed some of the code. but now the question is how can I wrapping this method in Task.Run ?

Comment: I do not understand. Just add a try and catch in each of these methods.

Comment: I had some mistakes with the way bitmaps sources were handled. what is important is that I know where the failure is.

Comment: An exception contains a stacktrace, that is how you find out what line is wrong. Was the problem solved? This question in its current state is useless to other people. I suggest you edit the question with a minimal example that reproduces the error so that others can test. Otherwise it might be best to delete the question.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd thank you for your advice … I hope like this it is easier to understand

Comment: Replace the `catch` with `catch(Exception exception)` and in the catch block log/write the exception. The current exception handling hides all exceptions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the file was too big for the Zip function to work.
this is the way to go:

```
settings.Values["Theme"] = selectedDynamicThemeName;
Stream themeZipFile = await fileName.OpenStreamForReadAsync(); ;
ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(themeZipFile);
```